# Status Code is 200 but still error event fires in ajax call to MVC web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ajaxq, asp.net-mvc-apiexplorer

I am posting some strings on a MVC based web api using [FromBody] which is working fine. Data is adding in database. My Controller's Action method type is HttpResponseMessage and i am returning this response

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "value"); 
return response;
```

but error event is firing instead of success.

Here is the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://businessworxapi.azurewebsites.net/api/SaveTemplate',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    dataType: "text json",
    data: "RetailerID=" + encodeURIComponent(retailerid) + "&SvgContent=" +
            encodeURIComponent(stringsvg) + "&Description=" +
            encodeURIComponent(Description) + "&TemplateName=" +
            encodeURIComponent(Name),
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    success: function (response) {
        alert("Added");
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Suggest me something to solve this issue.

Comment: Is there a Module or Handler in the MVC application that works on the requests after they are processed?

Comment: i don't think so.. because another api like this is working in the same manner.

Comment: What is the HTTP Status Code within the response on the client?

Comment: the HTTP Status code is 200

Comment: OK, so we have it narrowed down to something in your JavaScript.

Comment: Is it a cross site call?

Comment: You can use Chrome Dev Tools to see actual request and response, what Content-Type server returns for your request? You are using `text json` did you mean `application/json`?

Comment: i don't know where the problem is. Chrome dev tool also showing status 200. But still error event fires.

Comment: @csharpfolk i also tried with application/json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution for this question. Need to set two things. 
First is to set the value of custom header in web.config of MVC Web Api i.e Access-Control-Allow-Origin (the value should be the origin URL from where API is to be called). And second one is more important. "datatype" in ajax call is "json" so it was expecting a valid JSON result from API, Whereas the result returning from API is just a HTTPResponseMessage having code 200 and a string "value". I figured out that the error is parsingerror. So here i returned a valid json object instead of string "value".

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK , new { responseValue = "Value" });
return response;
```

it worked for me and success event of ajax call fired. Bingo :)